# Command Cooldown - discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so I did a bit of research on how to make a feature like this and this is what I came up with:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.send("Success")
    except commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown:
        await ctx.send("This command is on cooldown")
```

What is the best way to make the bot send something like this:
"You are on cooldown, try again in 26s"? I attempted to do this in the line `except commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown:` but this does not work.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the error using [`Command.error()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.error)

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Success")


@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(error)
```